# Is there anyway to modify request body before it gets bind to controller action method in asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

i am trying to send encrypted request to asp.net web api and want web api to intercept the request and decrypt or modify it before it gets bind to controller action method.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Have a look at [Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) "You can replace some parts of the process with your own custom behaviors. In this article, I describe the default behavior."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is write your custom filter. Since you want to decode the body content before it gets bind, you will have to use AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class DecryptRequestContent : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var requestContent = actionContext.Request.Content;
        var newContent = Decryption (requestContent);
        actionContext.Request.Content = newContent;
    }
}
```

After that, you will have to decorate your API with this filter like this:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [DecryptRequestContent]
    public void SomeMethod(DataModel model)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how to set actionContext.Request.Content , i mean what would be the type of newContent , is it a plain string , json object or some other format.

Comment: Request in actionContext.Request is of HttpRequestMessage type. The type of HttpRequestMessage is determined by the Content-Type of the request. While sending the request, whatever content-type was set at your request would be the type of that httpmessage. You can set newContent of type string and setting the value in proper format as per your content-type

Comment: my Decryption method return object which i serialize to json and assign it to 
actionContext.Request.Content but it is giving me compile time error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

           var newContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
            actionContext.Request.Content = newContent;

Please help

Comment: try changing the type of newContent from var to string

Comment: still the same error on this Line:
  actionContext.Request.Content = newContent;

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' when i assign json string to actionContext.Request.Content

Comment: here is the code:

 public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var requestContent = actionContext.Request.Content;
            //var a= requestContent.GetType();
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            object employee = Decryption(requestContent);
            string newContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
            actionContext.Request.Content = newContent;
        }

Comment: try this: actionContext.Request.Content = new StringContent(newContent);

Comment: Now when i used actionContext.Request.Content = new StringContent(newContent); 

I am getting runtime error as 'No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Employee' from content with media type 'text/plain'

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is

```
actionContext.Request.Content = new StringContent(newContent,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
```

Hopefully it can help!

Answer (score 0):

Updated for .net core, authorization attribute that changes the body of the request

```
 public class Authorize0ActionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
 {
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
            var requestContent = new StringContent("new body", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var stream = requestContent.ReadAsStream();//modified stream

            context.HttpContext.Request.Body = stream;

        }
    }

    public class Authorize0Attribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public Authorize0Attribute()
            : base(typeof(Authorize0ActionFilter))
        {
            //Arguments = new object[] { permission };
        }
    }
```